# toInclude is not a function

Tags: enzyme, jestjs

I’ve just upgraded from React 15 to 16 and and trying to resolve several issues with my test setup.. In my Enzyme/Expect setup. The biggest one is:

```
TypeError: (0 , _expect2.default)(...).toInclude is not a function
```

My test looks like this:

```
it('renders package with license selected', () => {
    const renderedComponent = mount(
        <Packages breakpoints={ { gtLarge: true } } packages={ data } />
    );
    renderedComponent.find('div').first().text()).toInclude('First Name');
});
```

This…

```
renderedComponent.find('div').first().text()
```

renders this…

```
First Name
Last Name
```

Has `toInclude()` changed with my upgrade to `"jest": "22.1.4",`? I can’t seem to find the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Jest, you may now use instead [toMatchObject(...)](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/expect.html#tomatchobjectobject)

Answer (score 0):

Why not the following:

```
expect(renderedComponent.find('div').first()).to.contain.text('First Name');
```